# Problem iterating through an array, which has been grouped

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, swift4, xcode10

I have a tableViewCell, which contains a collectionView which would display some cells. I've linked up the data to firebase, which would be shown in this tableView.

I currently am facing a problem where I have grouped a an array of a certain struct, using the new Dictionary grouping function(This I did in my TableViewCell).

Once this has been done I try iterating through this in a collectionView cell, in the cellforItemAtIndexPath.

What I notice though, is that when I run the code, my cells on display the latter part of the iteration, so the last segment of it.

Please find below my code for the tableView:

```
struct WebsiteStruct{
var title: String
var description: String
var banner: String
var link: String
}

var siteInfos: [WebsiteStruct] = []
var siteSections: [String] = []

class Websites: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

    let websitesRef = Database.database().reference().child("Schools").child(Variables.schoolName).child("Websites")

    websitesRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        for site in snapshot.children {
            if let siteSnapshot = site as? DataSnapshot{
                let siteInfo = siteSnapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                siteInfos.append(WebsiteStruct(title: siteInfo?.value(forKey: "title") as! String, description: siteInfo?.value(forKey: "description") as! String, banner: siteInfo?.value(forKey: "banner") as! String, link: siteInfo?.value(forKey: "link") as! String))
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    for website in siteInfos{
        let section = website.description
        if !siteSections.contains(section){
            siteSections.append(section)
        }
    }
    return siteSections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "websiteSectionCell") as! WebsiteSectionCell
    cell.displayContent(sectionTitle: siteSections[indexPath.row], indexPath: indexPath.row)
    return cell
}
}
```

Here is the code for my collectionViewCell:

```
class WebsiteSectionCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var websiteCornerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var Title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var websiteCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var currentIndexPath: Int = 0
let groupedSites = Dictionary(grouping: siteInfos, by: { $0.description })

func displayContent(sectionTitle: String, indexPath: Int){
    websiteCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = Variables.cornerRadius
    websiteCornerView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    Title.text = sectionTitle
    currentIndexPath = indexPath
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    websiteCollectionView.dataSource = self as UICollectionViewDataSource
    websiteCollectionView.delegate = self as UICollectionViewDelegate
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    //Set selected
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    for site in groupedSites[siteSections[currentIndexPath]]!{
        print(site.title)
    }
    print(groupedSites[siteSections[currentIndexPath]]!)
    return groupedSites[siteSections[currentIndexPath]]!.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! WebsiteCell
    for site in groupedSites[siteSections[currentIndexPath]]!{
        cell.displayContent(title: site.title, banner: Variables.schoolBanner!)
        print(indexPath)
    }
    return cell
}
}
```

Here's a screenshot of how this looks.

[image: Normally, the "School" cells should be Test Site 1 and Test site 2, not only Test site 2. Same goes for the utility cells.]

I don't know if it's somehow related, but the collectionView cellForItemAt indexPath function seems to run the code 4 times, when it's meant to run it only 2 times.

Some important information: All my data has been grouped together properly and when I print it in the console, the correct arrays are shown:

```
[EEB3App.WebsiteStruct(title: "Site 1", description: "School", banner: "/", link: "/"), EEB3App.WebsiteStruct(title: "Site 2", description: "School", banner: "/", link: "/")]

[EEB3App.WebsiteStruct(title: "Site 3", description: "Utility", banner: "/", link: "/"), EEB3App.WebsiteStruct(title: "Site 4", description: "Utility", banner: "/", link: "/")]
```

Comment: You can't have a loop in `numberOfRowsInSection` since that function will be called multiple times, causing `siteSections` to have duplicates. You should set up `siteSections` where younretrieve the data.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. `siteSections` can't have duplicates though, because of the way I've coded it. It only appends to `siteSections` if the value to append doesn't already exist in `siteSections`.

Comment: Can you show the code for your cells, especially `cell.displayContent` and `prepareForReuse`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code is very hard to read. I suggest to maybe at least refactor the struct into a different file.

The other thing is you need to check this particular line of code. It's not an ordered array and may return the same value to you.

```
let groupedSites = Dictionary(grouping: siteInfos, by: { $0.description })
```

This should've been declared and used in WebsitesViewController instead of doing the logic in the cell.  You can replace the array of `siteSections` and array `siteInfos` of with this.